# How to delete / replace layer in existing model?

Tags: pytorch

1. How to delete some layers from pretrained network (for example remove single ReLU activation layer)?
2. How to replace some layers by type in pretrained network (for example replace MaxPool2d with AvrPool)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you *know* the structure of your model, you can:

```
>>> model = torchvision.models(pretrained=True)
```

- Select a submodule and interact with it as you would with any other `nn.Module`. This will depend on your model's implementation. For example, submodule are often accessible via attributes (*e.g.* `model.features`), however this is not always the case, for instance nn.Sequential use indices: `model.features[18]` to select one of the relu activations. Also do note: not all layers are registered inside the `nn.Module`, non-parametric functions such as most activation functions can be applied via the functional approach directly in the forward of the module.
- For a given `nn.Module` `m` you can extract its layer name by using `type(m).__name__`. A canonical approach is to filter the layers of `model.modules` and only keep the max pool layers, then replace those with average pool layers:

  ```
  >>> maxpools = [k for k, m in model.named_modules() 
  ...                if type(m).__name__ == 'MaxPool2d']
  ['features.4', 'features.9', 'features.16', 'features.23', 'features.30']
  ```

  We can extract the parent module name for each of those layers:

  ```
  >>> maxpools = [k.split('.') for k, m in model.named_modules() 
  ...                if type(m).__name__ == 'MaxPool2d']
  [['features', '4'],
   ['features', '9'],
   ['features', '16'],
   ['features', '23'],
   ['features', '30']]
  ```

  Here they all come from the same parent module `model.features`. Finally, we can fetch the layer reference in order to overwrite their value:

  ```
  >>> for *parent, k in maxpools:
  ...     model.get_submodule('.'.join(parent))[int(k)] = nn.AvgPool2d(2,2)
  ```

  Resulting in:

  ```
  VGG(
    (features): Sequential(
      (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (4): AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
      (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (8): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (9): AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
      (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (13): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (15): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (16): AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
      (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (18): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (20): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (22): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (23): AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
      (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (25): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (27): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (29): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (30): AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
    )
    (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(7, 7))
    (classifier): Sequential(
      (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
      (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (2): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
      (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
      (4): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (5): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
      (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
    )
  )
  ```

Comment: You have saved many lives thank you so much I love you